# Footer outside ng-view / other iscroll implementation

Tags: angularjs, iscroll, iscroll4

I am building an application using phonegap & twitter bootstrap (with angularui-bootstrap).
Alter many hours spent on getting fixed header and footer done with CSS I've decided to go
with an "iscroll" solution.

The problem is that my footer is dynamic and gets scope variables from controller.
The "iscroll" functionality is binded to div with id="wrapper" via angularjs directive.

At the moment, I'm using ng-include at the end of each template, but using this solution
I will have multiple divs with id="wrapper".

Sample could looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="footer"></div>
<div ng-view>
<!-- below goes data from template via controller -->
<div id="wrapper" ng-iscroll>
<!-- here goes scrollable content -->
Offer 1
Offer 2
...
</div><!-- end of scrollable div>
<div id="footer">Some footer data.. if wrapper displays offer list, show "refresh button, and next/previous offers page buttons, and "add new offer button".
 If it displays "new offer" phase.. show "offer list" button....etc</div>
</div><!-- end of ng-view div -->
</body>
</html>
```

The above would make only the desired content scrollable.. but I cannot use multiple divs in the same html file.

The second solution I tried is similar, but I moved all the controller content to wrapper itself which made my footer scrollable too.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="footer"></div>
<div id="wrapper" ng-iscroll>
<div ng-view>
<!-- below goes data from template via controller -->
<!-- here goes scrollable content -->
Offer 1
Offer 2
...
<div id="footer">Some footer data.. if wrapper displays offer list, show "refresh button, and next/previous offers page buttons, and "add new offer button".
 If it displays "new offer" phase.. show "offer list" button....etc</div>
<!-- end of scrollable div>
</div><!-- end of ng-view div -->
</body>
</html>
```

I could maybe put footer outside ng-view in the index.html file but how do I attach the scope to it?

It's an "application design" question but I'm sure there are many user who need similar and they would find your thoughts helpful.